# Using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE with a DLL that may be loaded multiple times

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Using Qt 4.8 with C++. I'm working with application plugins that are loaded and unloaded at runtime. The same plugin may be loaded multiple times during the application's lifetime. One of these plugins uses `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on some types that need to be stored in a `QVariant`. When the plugin is reloaded later, the old declaration still points to the original memory space of the now-unloaded library. This results in access violations when Qt tries to create a `QVariant` from the re-declared meta type. We've already dealt with a similar issue with `qRegisterMetaType()`: we register meta types when the library is loaded and unregister those types just before the library is unloaded.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be an option when declaring rather than registering meta types.

How can we effectively handle cases where the library that declares a meta type is loaded and unloaded multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Kuba Ober's answer, you need to unregister the meta type by calling `QMetaType::unregisterType()` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#unregisterType) with your type name prior to unloading your DLL.  You should be able to unregister declared meta types in the same location that you unregister the types you've registered using `qRegisterMetaType<T>`.  This should leave the Qt Meta Object system in a clean state (as least as far as your unloaded plug-in is concerned), so that the next time the plug-in is loaded, new meta type IDs will be generated.  Specifically, when the DLL is loaded again, the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro will register your type again, this time with a new `metatype_id`, and `QVariant` should no longer give you access violations.

Comment: I [wasn't able to find the ](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/search-results.html?q=qUnregisterMetaType) qUnregisterMetaType macro anywhere in the qt documentation.

Comment: The non-macro function is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#unregisterType  Assuming you use the default name, you can pass in the fully-qualified name of the class to the function and have it properly unregister the type.  It's worth noting that this function is not present in Qt 5, so if you ever intend to migrate there, find an alternative solution (like not unloading plug-ins).

Answer (score 1):

When you look at what Q_DECLARE_METATYPE does, you see that it declares a template class specialization of `QMetaTypeId<T>` with a single `qt_metatype_id()` member that uses a static variable to store the value of `qRegisterMetaType`. If, as you claim, you're able to unregister the metatype, you're all set.